# Problemas no javascript e html

Tags: javascript, html, array, aplicação-web, sublime-text

Estou repetindo um projeto de site simples que vi no youtube( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__6lUT5TSYs&list=PLGwqoftZstLZUQGt3GeLpI-QAZaT8ccVG&index=3 ) no meu código porém recebi esses erros
Uncaught TypeError: produto.salvar is not a function
onclick file:///C:/Users/Jeanf/Desktop/javascript/Index.html:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of class produto note: Previously declared at line 1, column 6

preciso muito fazer esse sisteminha, eu realmente não sei oq deu errado
o html:

S.M.U versão interativa

## Sistema de Macros Unificado

```
    </header>
        <main>
                <div class="title"> 
                    <h2>produtos</h2>
                    <spam>Lista de alimentos e seus macros</spam>
                </div>
                <div class="card"></div>

                <div class="lineinput">

                <label for="produto"></label>

                <input type="text" id="produto" placeholder="nome do alimento">

                    </div>

                    <div class="lineinput">

                        <label for="proteina"></label>
    
                        <input type="text" id="proteina" placeholder="quantidade de proteina">
    
                            </div>





                    <div class="card">
                        <button  type='button' onclick="produto.salvar()">salvar</button>
                        <button  type='button' onclick="produto.cancelar()">cancelar</button> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                            <table border="1">
                                <thead>
                                    <th class="center">ID</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Protéina</th>
                                    <th class="center">Ações</th>
                                </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbody">



                                    </tbody>
                            </table>

                    </div>
                    
                
            
        </main>
```

o javascript:
class produto{
    constructor(){
            this.id = 1;
            this.arrayprodutos = [];
    }
    salvar() {
      let produto = this.lerdados();
      console.log(produto);
    }
    lerdados(){
        let produto = {}
     produto.id = this.id;
     produto.nomeproduto = document.getElementById('produto').value;
     produto.proteina = document.getElementById('proteina').value;

```
    return produto;
}

cancelar() {

}
```

}
var produto = new produto()

Comment: olá, sugiro primeiro formatar seu código de forma que fique mais legível, use a um editor ou pode fazer online, aqui por exemplo: https://beautifier.io/  depois edite a coloque o código formatado na pergunta para facilitar a leitura

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o DOM não esteja totalmente carregado ou algo assim. Nesse caso é melhor não usar o onclick, a não ser que vc use uma biblioteca Jquery por ex.

Tenta isso
Coloca um id no botão de salvar e tira o onclick:

```
<button id='btnSalvar' type='button'>salvar</button>
```

add isso no teu script, para adicionar a chamada da função ao botão de salvar:

```
document.getElementById('btnSalvar').addEventListener('click', () => {
                produto.salvar();
            });
```

*Aqui vai uma dica, quando o nome de variavel ou função for composta por duas ou mais palavras, usa o padrão camel case que seria "arrayProduto" ou assim "array_produto", porque fica melhor para vc ler e entender seu código depois.*

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).